# IndexOutOfBoundException(Java)

Tags: java

I get an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

from the code below which I think is perfectly fine!!
Any guidance will be warmly appreciated

```
for (int i = 0; i < allVacantRooms.size(); i++) {       
  String allavail=allVacantRooms.get(i).getName();
  System.out.println(allavail);
  for (int j = 0; j < deductableRooms.size(); j++) {
    String alldeduc=deductableRooms.get(j).getReservation()
                        .getReservedRooms().get(j).getRoom();
    System.out.println("allDeduc::"+alldeduc);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is with this line:

`String alldeduc = deductableRooms.get(j).getReservation().getReservedRooms().get(j).getRoom();`

The `get()` on `ReservedRooms` is dangerous!

It seems like you have 2 `deductableRooms` but only 1 `reservedRoom` in `deductableRoom.get(1)`.

[image]

Maybe you need a third loop over your `reservedRooms`.
Depends on what you are actually trying to do.
Right now you are printing the `ReservedRoom` as `deductRoom` which seems strange to me

Comment: i need to deduct the reserved rooms from the available ones,so to just see   what it prints!!Yeah the use of third loop worked fine..

Answer (score 1):

You are blindly using the same index on reservationRooms as you are on the reservation they belong to. You should iterate over the room in a separate loop.

Also, your code style is poor; prefer a "for each" loop when you don't need the index (as here).

Also also, the outer loop is not related to the inner loop; they should be separate loops.

Try something like:

```
for (ReservedRoom room : allVacantRooms) {
    System.out.println(room.getName());
}
for (ReservedRoom room : deductableRooms) {
    for (ReservedRoom reservedRoom : room.getReservation().getReservedRooms()) {
        System.out.println("allDeduc::" + reservedRoom.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,suggestions taken!!

Answer (score 0):

```
String alldeduc=deductableRooms.get(j).getReservation()
                        .getReservedRooms().get(j).getRoom();
```

In the above statement, we cannot be sure that the number of deductableRooms is equal to no of reservedrooms therefore a bette approach would be

```
RerservedRoom reservedRooms =deductableRooms.get(j).getReservation()
                            .getReservedRooms();
String alldeduc = "";
for(int k = 0; 
    k < reservedRooms.size() /*whichever method the get the total number of rooms*/;
    k++)
{
     alldeduc += reservedRooms.get(k).getRoom();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
String alldeduc=deductableRooms.get(j).getReservation()
                    .getReservedRooms().get(j).getRoom();
```

On `getReservedRooms().get(j)`, you are trying to get the item with an index, without checking whether there is an item present or not.

Comment: problem was not with item not being available,it has worked with use of anther loop.